# Fabric.js drag event does not work

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I started to use fabric.js recently and can't set up clicking events. 
I guided by [this](http://fabricjs.com/touch-events/) page. 

HTML:

```
<section class="canvas-wrap">
    <canvas id="main-canvas" width="1903" height="885"></canvas>
</section>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('main-canvas');
canvas.on({'touch:drag':function() {
    console.log('dragging');
});
```

Nothing fancy, but it does not work.

Please, tell me if something is wrong or I should use other way.

Answer (score 2):

At the top of the [guide](http://fabricjs.com/touch-events/), `This demo uses custom version of Fabric with touch events enabled`.
Therefore, you need to use custom builded fabric.js which includes `gesture` module.

The detail of how to build is written in https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js

Answer (score 0):

I use mouse down event like this:

```
myObject.on('mouse:down', function( options ) {
    if (options.target != undefined) {
      //do something when clicking;
    }
});
```